# iOS Memory malady madness

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I recently ported a project over to ARC as I was having trouble with crashes and actually determining the cause, whether it was leaks or retain cycles etc., Now I have ported it over, I have not done massive testing to see whether it still crashes as I have not managed to get passed the activity monitor giving me the heeby jeebies when it shows my application doing This (activity monitor profiler)

[image: activity monitor]

whereas in allocations tools it looks something like

[image: allocations]

That real memory usage is not even the worst of it, at one point it shot up to around 90 odd MBs, I am unsure on how to proceed as I am not 100 percent sure what to do with the information given here, Except assume that I might be dong something, very wrong, And I have also run the leaks instrument, I have a few but they are minimal, they are all in bytes.

Does anyone have an explanation? or at the very least are able to clarify what I am possibly looking at? what's the difference between `real memory usage` and `live bytes` and `overall bytes`? Also these results were gotten doing exactly the same actions once and then showing you at the end of it.

I have been trying to reduce the real memory usage as pre ARC conversion I was having memory warnings and silent crashes frequently, I have not run into these again after converting, but I have not done any prolonged testing as I cannot conceive of even trying when the real memory usage looks like that. Which actually looks a lot higher than before ARC...Although the live bytes does look lower post ARC...Madness!

Answer (score 1):

Something that confused me for a while is that ARC - wonderful as it is - does not necessarily avoid the need for `@autoreleasepool`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html

I ran very large memory usage in an app until someone suggested:

```
@autoreleasepool {

    // lots of allocating of objects returned from methods then discarded

} // and the closing brace of the autoreleasepool block causes their memory to be recovered here
```

Maybe that will help you.

A good explanation of the meaning of the various columns in the profiler is at [Instruments ObjectAlloc: Explanation of Live Bytes & Overall Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154219/instruments-objectalloc-explanation-of-live-bytes-overall-bytes)

Comment: I did consider that i possibly have a loop somewhere with a lot of autorelease objects being allocated but i was told to ignore that notion as you know that memory will get released eventually. However I shall try this...Thanks