# Cocos2d: is there a way to know which images are still loaded in memory?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2d 2.0 and XCode 4.5.2 and I do wonder **how I can detect which spritesheets/images are still on memory at a specific time.**

Example: 
In Scene I load images.pvr.ccz spritesheet, then I call replaceScene loading Scene2. Whilst Scene2 is running I want to see if images.pvr.ccz is still in memory as the [resident memory increases at each scene.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642421/understanding-task-basic-info-task-resident-size)

Should I use some instrument tool or shall I instead add some breakpoint in the texture cache related classes?

I do add the images to the frameCache as following:

```
 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"images.plist"];
        batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"images.pvr.ccz"];
        [self addChild:batchNode];
```

---

### Additional details - not needed

I have the following beheaviour: every time I replace a scene the memory increases by the "x" MB that could correspond to the spritesheet size.

I added those calls at the init method of each scene, however the memory still increases:

```
    [CCAnimationCache purgeSharedAnimationCache];
    [CCShaderCache purgeSharedShaderCache];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] removeUnusedSpriteFrames];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] dumpCachedTextureInfo];
```

Use this call to see what textures are load into the memory at the moment. Also if you want to remove unused textures, use

```
[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
```

Comment: I really don't understand. I added the calls and I get 1 texture for 8MB of usage but, looking at the resident memory info, I get an increase of 8MB each time I load the scene (hence the texture gets somehow re-loaded each time). I am lost.. :(

Comment: The texture is loaded into memory only once. Are you sure that your memory is leaked because of textures? No large amounts of data, sounds or something else loaded?

Comment: I added a CCLOG to print the textKey on the dumbInfo and the spritesheet of the previous scene gets cached. I guess that this should explain part of the memory increase. However I have no idea on how to force its removal.

Comment: make sure that there all objects from your previous scene are destroyed after you replacing scene.

Comment: I added "[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeAllTextures];" and the texture sheet get removed, however the memory stays the same. I guess that need to investigate the rest as u suggested in the second comment.

Comment: What is the standard way to make sure that all objects are destroyed? Should I look for the object name in the Allocation tool and if I don't see the name then means that has been destroyed? The issue is that I am using ARC and I got no dealloc method where I can play with this.

Comment: I checked with Allocation tool for the name of classes of the previous scenes but they do not show. Mystery :)

Comment: @Marion (1/2)I have used your approach plus a dump of the amount of resident memory. Initially I was getting confused as I was calling the resident memory dump info function in the init method of the new scene. This was causing a concurrency problem as the 2 scene are alive at the same time and hence the assets are stil in memory so the memory was "not" decreasing. Adding a callback with a 0.1 seconds delay solved the issue. However there are cases (in scenes with no images the removeAllTexture does not work straight away and I do still get the memory loaded after 0.1seconds and even 1 second)

Comment: (2/2) it just seem not to trigger the texture removal if there is no other texture being loaded in the init method. I find this weird as it should behave the same way (the texture removal is called as first thing in both cases). I have put this in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706146/cocos2d-removespriteframes-and-removealltextures-do-not-work-straight-away/18706277?noredirect=1#comment27591645_18706277 however I accepted the answer as the answer makes sense for most of the cases (this is a specific case and would be nice if anyone can solve it, if so please add as answer)